# How do I change a button's autoResizingMask when using storyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Sorry for the newbie question, I'm very new to this (and just going through the stanford lectures in iTunes). I'm trying to stop buttons resizing when I change their title. Someone on freenode told me I should:

> button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoResisingFlexibleWidth;

How do I add code to the view? I tried clicking the "Show the version editor" but it displayed XML (and changing that didn't do anything).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: You should consider adding some *text* to this answer to explain why it works.  (and if you can find it, a link to the documentation is always nice.)

Comment: I don't seem to have an instantiation of my view, or an object called TestProjectView I can instantiate. Where can I get it from? I tried MainStoryboard.storyboard but it doesn't find it as a class.